# plotly.scatter figure doesnt reset when updating with callback (python dash)

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

I have the following problem:

I try to plot a plotly.scatter plot combined with dash which should be changeable with sliders using callback.
I searched through the documentation of dash and plotly and found some examples for basic and advanced callbacks and also for Sliders

https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks

https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/slider

The Sliders are working and the shown data is also changing but the old plot doesnt vanish even if i reload the page.
I dont know if the problem is in the html component or in the callback.

```
from math import cos,sin,radians
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import pandas as pd
```

I skip the calculation which is not called in the callback because im quite sure the problem isnt there but if you want i can provide it aswell.

```
def s_out(XTvar, YTvar, ZTvar, XCvar, YCvar, ZCvar):
    for a in np.linspace(0,360,3600):
        s1i=cos(radians(a))
        s2i=sin(radians(a))
        fe=fE_tsaiwu((s1i,s2i,0,0,0,0),getm(XTvar, YTvar, ZTvar, XCvar, YCvar,ZCvar))
        s1.append(s1i/fe)
        s2.append(s2i/fe)
    return s1, s2

s1, s2 = s_out(XTvar, YTvar, ZTvar, XCvar, YCvar, ZCvar)
```

Html component with callback:
(Initialising the figure in the Div is not even necessary i figured out)

```
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='Tsai',
        # figure=fig
        figure = {}
    ),
    html.H3(children='XTvar'),
    html.H5(children='Der Wert des Sliders wird hier direkt unter dem momentanen Punkt angezeigt'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id= "XTvar",
        min = 1,
        max = 1500,
        value = 1000,
           tooltip={"placement": "bottom", "always_visible": True}
    ),
    html.H3(children='YTvar'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id= "YTvar",
        min = 1,
        max = 50,
        value = 40,
    ),
    html.H3(children='ZTvar'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id= "ZTvar",
        min = 1,
        max = 50,
        value = 40,
    ),
    html.H3(children='XCvar'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id= "XCvar",
        min = 500,
        max = 1000,
        value = 700,
    ),
    html.H3(children='YCvar'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id= "YCvar",
        min = 100,
        max = 150,
        value = 120,
    ),
    html.H3(children='ZCvar'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id= "ZCvar",
        min = 100,
        max = 150,
        value = 120,
    )
])
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='Tsai', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='XTvar', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='YTvar', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='ZTvar', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='XCvar', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='YCvar', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='ZCvar', component_property='value')
)
def updatefigure(XTvar, YTvar, ZTvar, XCvar, YCvar, ZCvar):
    df = zip(s_out(XTvar, YTvar, ZTvar, XCvar, YCvar, ZCvar))
    fig = px.scatter(df,s1, s2)
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Here you can see what is happening if i move one of the sliders.

[image: Initial State]

[image: After slider movement]

I appreciate every kind of help and i hope the problem is well described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic in your dash callback is incomplete.

If you take a look at `s1, s2` after you move your slider, you can find their length is increasing by 3600 every time you move your slider, since you never clear `s1, s2` after each call to the callback.

Therefore everytime you move your slider, you are drawing a new eclipse by appending new values to `s1, s2`!

[image]

Here are some advises to your code, to avoid this behaviour.

1. Avoid defining global variables like `s1, s2 = s_out(XTvar, YTvar, ZTvar, XCvar, YCvar, ZCvar)` in your code. Global variables is a cache in your Dash app, and its value persist until you kill your debugging session. We have little control to them in Dash. See [Dash Documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks) for details.
   If you need to cache some values between callbacks, use [dcc.Store](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store)
2. Use Dash built-in debugger to see what is inside the callbacks. It could be useful to trace more complex callbacks.